# How do I test keras CNN model for images

Tags: image-processing, keras, conv-neural-network

First time learning keras and I wanted to make a model that can classify pictures between chicken and nature.

```
train = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255)
validation = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255)


train_data = train.flow_from_directory('./train', target_size=(200, 200), batch_size=3, class_mode='binary')

validation_data = validation.flow_from_directory('./testchickens', target_size=(200, 200), batch_size=3, class_mode='binary')



model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16,(3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(200,200,3)),
                               tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2), 
                               tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3), activation='relu'),
                               tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2),
                               tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3), activation='relu'),
                               tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2),
                               tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
                               tf.keras.layers.Dense(512,activation='relu'),
                               tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')
                               ])



model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=RMSprop(learning_rate=0.001), metrics=['accuracy'])

model_fit = model.fit(train_data, steps_per_epoch=3, epochs=10, validation_data = validation_data)
```

highest score I got was 88.89% in my model. I realized as I was coding the model that I needed 3 separate data sets or files for my images (training, validation, test).

To test my model I downloaded a few pictures off google that weren't in either of my training or validation files but I am not sure how I can test my model on the sample pictures I got. I figured I can convert the image to an array but the output feels off.

```
sample = glob.glob('./sample/**/*.jpg', recursive=True)
x = sample[0]
img1 = image.load_img(x, target_size=(200, 200, 3))
X = image.img_to_array(img1)
X = np.expand_dims(X, axis=0)
image = np.vstack([X])
model.predict(image)
```

For some reason my model classifies every single picture as a chicken when clearly I had pictures of trees and forests in my sample or test file. Before the last block of code I ran into a lot of issues with my input not fitting the dimensions/shapes/layers etc so I think if I understood how the structure works on my model maybe I can fix it? If someone can please explain what my issue is or point me to some resource that explains the layering/arrays of keras models I would greatly appreciate.

Comment: You are not rescaling the pixel values by dividing with 255.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy for what/where? my sample?

Comment: After you load the new image, this is what you trained your model with: ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255), you need to replicate this preprocessing when loading new samples.